# functional or conditional error

Tags: c++, function

functional or conditional error, error occur at the closing braces of getval() might be due to conditions in while loop, but why , please tell reason of error,
in this ques i need to input 5 test score from users which must be in between 0 to 100 , that's why i include some condition in do while loop in getval(), if i exclude the do while loop then program runs fine , please tell me reason of error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, lwst;

void getval()
{
    do{
        cin >> sub1;
        cin >> sub2;
        cin >> sub3;
        cin >> sub4;
        cin >> sub5;
    } while ((sub1 < 101 && sub1 >= 0) &&
        (sub2 < 101 && sub2 >= 0) &&
        (sub3 < 101 && sub3 >= 0) &&
        (sub4 < 101 && sub4 >= 0) &&
        (sub5 < 101 && sub5 >= 0)
        )
}


int findlowest()

{
    int s1 = sub1;
    int s2 = sub2;
    int s3 = sub3;
    int s4 = sub4;
    int s5 = sub5;
    int temp = 0;

    while (s1&&s2&&s3&&s4&&s5)
    {
        s1--;
        s2--;
        s3--;
        s4--;
        s5--;
        temp++;
    }
    return temp;

}
void calavg()
{
    cout << "average is " << (sub1 + sub2 + sub3 + sub4 + sub5 - lwst) / 4;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "enter the test score , marks from 0 to 100\n";
    getval();
    lwst = findlowest();
    calavg();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What* error? Please always include the error message you get. Also indent the code properly so it's possible to follow it better.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the final closing right-paren of your while-condition in `getval`. You're also completely ignoring any IO errors, but that's a different issue.

Comment: This code is riddled with global variables, plus violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule). Use a `std::vector` for those integer values if they're intended to be related.

Comment: i am new to programming  , please don't down vote me. instead of down voting me tell me my mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is a sintax error - you lose `;` after `while`.

Function `getval` must be like:

```cpp
void getval()
{
    do{
        cin >> sub1;
        cin >> sub2;
        cin >> sub3;
        cin >> sub4;
        cin >> sub5;
    } while ((sub1 < 101 && sub1 >= 0) &&
        (sub2 < 101 && sub2 >= 0) &&
        (sub3 < 101 && sub3 >= 0) &&
        (sub4 < 101 && sub4 >= 0) &&
        (sub5 < 101 && sub5 >= 0)
        );
}
```

After it compiles, consider changing the condition in this while loop - I suppose that OR (`||`) will be more suitable if you want forcing user to enter values in range 0..100 - e.g.:

```cpp
void getval()
{
    do{
        cin >> sub1;
        cin >> sub2;
        cin >> sub3;
        cin >> sub4;
        cin >> sub5;
    } while ((sub1 < 0 || sub1 > 100) ||
             (sub2 < 0 || sub2 > 100) ||
             (sub3 < 0 || sub3 > 100) ||
             (sub4 < 0 || sub4 > 100) ||
             (sub5 < 0 || sub5 > 100)
            );
}
```

And even after that there are lots of points for improvements:

1. I prefer 5 independent loops to enter and check each value (now if one value is incorrect user will be asked to enter all values once again);
2. names `sub1`...`sub5` looks like good candidates to be items in the array `sub[5]`
3. it is not a good style to use global variables to pass data from one function to another

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional in the `while` needs to be reversed.

```
do{
      cin>>sub1;
      cin>>sub2;
      cin>>sub3;
      cin>>sub4;
      cin>>sub5;
} while( ! ((sub1<101 && sub1>=0)&&
            (sub2<101 && sub2>=0)&&
            (sub3<101 && sub3>=0)&&
            (sub4<101 && sub4>=0)&&
            (sub5<101 && sub5>=0)) );
```

Your code will be easier to understand if you move the conditional code to a function.

```
do{
      cin>>sub1;
      cin>>sub2;
      cin>>sub3;
      cin>>sub4;
      cin>>sub5;
} while( ! variables_within_limits(sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5) );
```

and implement the function as:

```
bool variables_within_limits(int sub1, int sub2, int sub3, int sub4, int sub5)
{
   return (sub1<101 && sub1>=0)&&
          (sub2<101 && sub2>=0)&&
          (sub3<101 && sub3>=0)&&
          (sub4<101 && sub4>=0)&&
          (sub5<101 && sub5>=0);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this society is heaven for new programmer :)